# My object and the armature when parenting, the automatic weight doesnt even apply

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I made a video game character mesh which is highly detailed with lots of faces. It has multiple vertex groups. I was using a tutorial but he was using a simple character so it worked easily for him. Mine when parenting the weight paint didn't even appear as if it didn't even work.

How to resolve this issue?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxP_VyE2XPZonjEcJy95IgRLTDpGit3K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices, select your object, switch to *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

Comment: THANKS it worked